# NodeMedia Server Deployment

Tags: node.js, server, node-modules, live-streaming, node-media-server

I want to deploy Node Media Server application on a shared hosting Cpanel,
I have hosted the node application but I am unaware how to get the rtmp url which is predefined in the node media server manual to rtmp://localhost/live.

For example I have hosted my node js application on example.com/first/second. I want to know what will be the rtmp url generated from it?

For example I have hosted my node js application on example.com/first/second. I want to know what will be the rtmp url generated from it?